# How can I filter the apachesolr_autocomplete results on a custom search block

Tags: search, ajax

We recently set up solr search and have been happy with it. I started using the custom_search module to set up pre-filtered search results, and while my solr search pages work well, the autocomplete search suggestions return ideas from the full site.

Is there any way to filter them based on content type?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the D.O issue for this:

https://www.drupal.org/node/1444038 (enables per-search-page support for autocomplete)

along with this...

https://www.drupal.org/node/326375 (enables having a search form block per each page)